# Javascript local to UTC time conversion off by two hours

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I'm trying to convert a date from local to midnight UTC so that I can then save into a SQL database and be able to query by matching dates. For example, if today is Sep 20, 2015 at any time in any time zone that I may be in, then I should end up with a timestamp of Sep 20, 2015, 0:00am UTC, but instead I end up with Sep 20, 2015, 2:00am UTC regardless of which time zone I set my clock to. This should be simple, but for some reason when I convert to UTC I end up off by two hours, so I delete 7200 seconds to get midnight. This seems to be working, but because I don't know why I'm off by two hours I'm afraid I may run into problems later. My code is below, only 4 lines. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setUTCFullYear(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());
date.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0);
dateUTC = date.getTime()/1000-7200;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what exactly isn't working, but you should use `Date.UTC()` and it will work:

```js
var date = new Date();
alert(Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate())/1000)
```

Comment: When I run this snippet, I am still off by two hours. Is anyone else seeing this issue?

Comment: Thanks Amit. Turned out my problem was not in Javascript, but in the PHP I was using to reconstruct the date server-side. I was using date(format, timestamp) where I needed to use gmdate(format, timestamp).

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of time zone difference you could try:

```
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - date.getTimezoneOffset())
```

Comment: UTC time is available from the UTC methods, the timezone offset should be added to local time, not subtracted. And the OP wants midnight…